# list all child custom posts from a parent when in child

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need a way to refer to a parent's of a current child post to add that short code to the child's post template in order to display in child's post all parent childs.

I think with an exemple is easier to understand :)

If I am in: "/Season-1/Episode-1".
I want to list in "Episode-1" all episodes from "Season-1",

but if I am in "/Season-2/Episode-19" 
I want to list in "Episode-19" all episodes from "Season-2".

Currently I am using this code to show list of child-posts for a specfic parent on any page, the problem is I don't know how to automatize the shortcode (or if php code needs to be changed to work automatically without slug).

```
function wpb_list_child_pages( $atts = array() ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id'   => 0,
    'slug' => '',
), $atts );

if ( $atts['slug'] ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $q = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_name = %s", $atts['slug'] );
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $q );

    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        return '';
    }
} else {
    $post_id = absint( $atts['id'] );
}

$post = get_post( $post_id ); // WP_Post on success.
$childpages = '';

if ( $post && is_post_type_hierarchical( $post->post_type ) ) {
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'title_li' => '',
        'post_type' => 'season',
        'echo'     => 0,
    ) );
}

if ( $childpages ) {
    $childpages = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $childpages;
}
add_shortcode( 'wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages' );`
```

Then I use this shortcode where I want to show the specific child list:

With the post ID: 
`[wpb_childpages id="{POST_ID} /]`
E.g. `[wpb_childpages id="123" /]`

With the post slug: `[wpb_childpages slug="{SLUG} /]`
E.g. `[wpb_childpages slug="home" /]`

Comment: please help :) :)

Comment: any help? please